# Can we *ALWAYS* use $|x|$ whenever the integral of $f(x)$ requires?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I am using a notebook of integral formulas.
I want to use $|x|$ whenever required.

However, I am afraid to miss some singularities.

So, is anyone familiar with an example where the solution is something like:
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx = \ln(f(x)) + C$$
$$\forall  \{x | f(x) > 0\} $$

and the shortcut solution of:
$$ \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx = \ln(|f(x)|) + C $$
failes?

In other words, is there a general proof for the following law:

Let $F(x)$ be a function with domain $D=\mathbb R_+ = \{x |x \in \mathbb R ,x > 0\}$
and let $f(x)=\frac{dF}{dx}$

Than,

$$ \int f(x)dx = F(|x|) + C $$

P.S. Assuming that the "poet's intention" is clear here, I would appreciate it if you wont "try to catch me" in small tipos or formalities.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are defining a function $F$ over a domain $x\geq 0$ but then you use $|x|$, which suggests you will try to evaluate the function outside of its intended domain.  This is generally not a good thing to pursue.  Your original integration fact holds because we can define $\log(f(x))$ when $f(x)$ is a positive valued function, and we can define $\log(-f(x))$ when $f(x)$ is a negative-valued function, and when we differentiate it "looks" like we get the same thing except that these are different functions $f$.

Comment: Also, don't mix the two functions (the postive one and negative one) by accidentally integrating across the boundary. For example $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx \neq \ln(|1|)-\ln(|-1|)$$

Comment: @Michael So, is there a general statement when the integral is defined only on positives or not?